# Extension of tensor field on manifold

Tags: analysis, reference-request, manifolds, tensors

In *Analysis on Manifolds*, James Munkres writes (on page 249):

> Any tensor field on $M$ [$M$ here is a (smooth) manifold which is a subset of
> $\mathbb{R}^n$] can be extended to a tensor field defined on an open
> set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $M$; the proof, however, is decidedly
> non-trivial.

Consequently, he neither provides a proof nor gives more details.  I'd be interested in sources (textbooks, preferably) where this statement is proved.  Also, does it have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial and sketched answer:** in the book of John Lee of Riemannian manifolds he says that any smooth vector field in an embedded submanifold can be extended to a vector field in some open subset of the ambient space (page 93). He says that this is related to an exercise, that consists to prove that for any smooth function $f: M\to \mathbb{R}$ there exists some open neighborhood $U$ of $M$ on the ambient space and some smooth $\tilde f: U\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\tilde f|_M=f$.

Then it seems that we can extend the result of the extension of vector fields to any other kind of tensor field, as all rely in smooth extensions of the coefficients of the tensor.